# jQuery sortable to find parent of the dropped div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the parent of the dropped div

```
$(".someclass").sortable
({
     connectWith: ".someclass",
     cancel: '.cart_header',

    receive: function(e, ui) 
    {
        var drag_id = ui.item.attr("id");
var parent_id = ui.item.parent().attr("id");
        alert("hi"+parent_id);
        var re_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(drag_id,re_id); 

    }

}).disableSelection();
```

Lets assume,

`List1` div contain following `div1`,`div2`,`div3` (id).

And List2 not contain divs.

Now I'm moving the `div1` from `List1` div to `List2` div.

In my above code give result is `div1` and `list2`. But I need to find the parent div where it is left from.

Comment: `someclass` will never work without `.` unless is a tag which I suppose is not. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Creating a minimal verifiable example will make things much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @lonut I forgot to add it. In my actual code there is no problem. My doubt is it is possible to find the parent div of the dragged div.

Comment: Please update the question with the `HTML` code also. It will be better also to add your actual code.